# How to minimize gaps on histogram in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

let's say I have two kind of data. One is in small range (from 0 to 0.5) and the other one is in large range (from 4 to 600). The first one is called `v` and the second one is called `mx`.

```
data<-structure(list(v = c(0.0741993337844943, 0.0469609897824665, 
0.27686789382899, 0.0899877689865293, 0.0533351613571831, 0.0949535942113873, 
0.132267448969788, 0.140736814439988, 0.170258755089611, 0.0012874981224646, 
0.0167425549755457), mx = c(20.2159112302004, 15.2656614271742, 
14.4361762323113, 8.87425807502441, 4.04997522826475, 34.9314254746675, 
45.699439750261, 16.0238858355385, 79.4436180395085, 598.247400459265, 
5.16677793308584)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))
```

I used these codes to plot;

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data, aes(x=v)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
ggplot(data, aes(x=mx)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
```

[image: plot_v][image: plot_mx]

For ex. As you see there is no value between 0.0 and 0.1 on the `v` plot. I want to add more values to this gap like 0.01, 0.02... and for the other plot I want to add more values like 0-10-20-30...200-210

In brief I want to minimize all gaps for all plots with different ranges.

Comment: Perhaps: `ggplot(data, aes(x=v)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)` ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve: your ```data``` simply does not contain any values where there are gaps in the charts - maybe ```geom_density()``` is visually closer to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
data<-structure(list(v = c(0.0741993337844943, 0.0469609897824665, 0.27686789382899, 0.0899877689865293, 0.0533351613571831, 0.0949535942113873,  0.132267448969788, 0.140736814439988, 0.170258755089611, 0.0012874981224646, 0.0167425549755457),
                     mx = c(20.2159112302004, 15.2656614271742, 14.4361762323113, 8.87425807502441, 4.04997522826475, 34.9314254746675, 45.699439750261, 16.0238858355385, 79.4436180395085, 598.247400459265, 5.16677793308584)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))


library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data, aes(x=data$v)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
ggplot(data, aes(x=data$mx)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)
```

By using the `bins` argument you tell `geom_histogram` to make 10 'bins', i.e. to group the values into ten equally sized groups of witdth range(x)/10.

This means the width of the bins is now fixed (given a range of values).

Alternatively (but not simoultanously) we can tell `geom_histogram` to use a given `binwidth` i.e. to group the values into groups of a given width.
Now the number of `bins` is range(x)/binwidth

Applied to your example:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=data$v)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.01)
```

[image: binwidth0.01]

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=data$mx)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=10)
```

[image: binwidth10]

Comment: You could also add `scale_x_log10()` to the bottom one to decrease the gaps, just beware that this may make the axis harder to comprehend.